# When installing eclipse, I cant find the jdk in my folder

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to all of this. I want to write java code and so I installed eclipse. When I try to run it, it says it cant find the jdk and it makes me browse the folder for it. I downloaded the exact one that it said, but I cant find it ANYWHERE. I cant find any of my other files when I'm browsing for the jdk in my folder. (e.g When I click on my documents tab there is nothing there)

Thanks!

Comment: You need to install JDK and then point that to eclipse

Comment: Have you mixed a 32-bit Eclipse with 64-bit JDK or vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a JDK compatible to eclipse you are using, and that JDK should be on your class path. You can set class path for here:

System properties ---> Environment variables --->system variables
Variable Name : JAVA_HOME
Value         : Location of java you installed (Eg:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101)

Then Edit the variable name with path  and provide this.%JAVA_HOME%\bin

Hope this will works for you.

Thanks
Hari

Answer (score 0):

System properties ---> Advanced---> Environment variables --->System variables ---> Path-> and add at the end of the list: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11 (or your path)\bin", Save & Close